# How do you output an average from a .txt file?

Tags: python, file, text, average

Hello I have been trying to output the contents of a .txt file.
What I need to do is find the average of the number of hours each worker does and out put it to the screen. I have worked on a bit of code but my .txt file contains 
str and integer:

```
Bobby:8
Sam:6
Kerry:4
```

I have started some code but can get it to work. My attempt:

```
elif viewwork==('week 1 hrs'):
    averageHours=[]
with open('week 1 hrs.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       if line.strip():
          averageHours.append(int(line.strip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will be useful for your problem.

Here `hours` is a dictionary (defaultdict) in which keys are the names and the values are  the list of integers (number of hours). We first read the lines from the file and append the number of hours to the dictionary. Then, we iterate over the keys in the dictionary (`hours`) and calculate the average for every name.

### Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

hours = defaultdict(list)

with open('a.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      stripped = line.strip()
      if stripped:
         parts = stripped.split(':')
         hours[parts[0]].append( int(parts[1]) )

for key in hours:
    print( '{},{}'.format(key, np.mean(hours[key])) )
```

### Input:

```
Bobby:8
Sam:6
Kerry:4
Bobby:10
Kerry:8
```

### Output:

```
Kerry,6.0
Sam,6.0
Bobby,9.0
```

Comment: Could you give me a brief description of what it does. Thanks @Sait

Comment: what does the word numpy represent after import? (module)

Comment: `numpy` is a library, you can use it to calculate the average: `np.mean([1,2,3])` will give you `2.0`. It is a good practice to use it since it makes the code more readable, compact and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for the average across workers. That is, take the average of all the numbers at the end of each line.

```
hours = [line.split(':')[1] for line in open('week 1 hrs.txt')]
average = sum(hours) / len(hours)
```

Instead, if you want the average hours for each worker:

```
from collections import defaultdict
hours = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('week 1 hrs.txt'):
    name, hour = line.split(':')
    hours[name] += hour
for name in hours:
    print('Average for {} is {}'.format(name, hours[name]/len(hours[name])))
```

Comment: What if there is an empty line at the end?

Comment: Hi yes @Chad Kennedy, could you explain what the defaultdict does thanks.

Comment: Think you want `line.split(':')` not `strip` in your first section of code

Comment: defaultdict says if you refer to a nonexistent item, it will create an item with a default value for you. For example, if you have an empty defaultdict, and you say hours['sam'] += 5, that entry didn't exist, so it's created for you, with the default int value (0), then 5 is added to it. With a normal dict, hours['sam'] += 5 would fail because you haven't yet created a 'sam' entry.

Comment: Are there any tutorials that i could get extra help with this subject on thanks